# Find the value of $p = 1 + \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\cos(k\theta)}{\cos^{k}(\theta)}$ when $\theta = \pi/6$

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry

> If $\theta=\frac{\pi}{6}$ and $$1+\sum_{k=1}^8\frac{\cos(k\theta)}{\cos^k\theta}=p$$ then find the value of $$\displaystyle\frac{\sin(9\theta)}{p\sin\frac{\pi}{6}\left(\cos\frac{\pi}{6}\right)^8}$$

Everything sees easy when $p$ isn't involved. I can calculate $p$ laboriously by putting in values of $k$ but then it won't be a good idea.

I'm having problem in calculating $p$. I believe that there should be a closed or a general form but I can't figure that out.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT**

Due to the DeMoivre's theorem, we can rearrange the proposed sum as follows:

\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\cos(k\theta)}{\cos^{k}(\theta)} = \text{Re}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{(\cos(\theta) + i\sin(\theta))^{k}}{\cos^{k}(\theta)} = \text{Re}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(1 + i\tan(\theta)\right)^{k}
\end{align*}

where the last expression is the sum of the $n$ first terms of a geometric sequence.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: This was extraordinary....just one doubt how to calculate $$\left(1+\frac{i}{\sqrt{3}}\right)^8$$

Comment: You may be interested in the following relation:

$$1 + z + z^{2} + \ldots + z^{n} = \frac{z^{n + 1} - 1}{z - 1}$$

Comment: I meant how to write the above expression in terms of power of $e$ like $re^{i\alpha}$ finding $r$ is not easy

Comment: You do not need to consider polar coordinates.

Comment: Oh yeah....i found out the value of the value of the expression by first finding it's square and repeating the process $4$ times